# How to match associate tables ID with AND condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have leads and tags associated with it. I want to fetch Leads that MUST have BOTH tags(9,13) and any others.

If I use IN query then it returns leads with OR condition and if use AND then it does not return.

any idea how to achieve this?

```
SELECT distinct [Leads].Id AS LeadId, Tags.Id, Tags.Name FROM [Leads]  
INNER JOIN [AssociateTags] ON [Leads].[Id] = [AssociateTags].[EntityId]
INNER JOIN [Tags] ON [AssociateTags].[TagId] = [Tags].[Id]
WHERE [Leads].[IsDeleted] = cast(0 as bit)  
AND leads.id= 17 and (tags.Id in (9, 13))
--AND leads.id= 17 and tags.Id = 9 and tags.Id = 13
```

Sample output

```
17  9   imported-from-google
17  13  imported-from-quickbooks
```

Total Records

```
17  9   imported-from-google
17  13  imported-from-quickbooks
17  14  imported-from-yahoo
```

Comment: `and tags.Id = 9 and tags.Id = 13` this can never be true. When can a **scalar** value be 2 different values? What's wrong with `IN`? What `OR` condition? There isn't one in your query. Also, why are you using a `DISTINCT` when you have `Tags.*`? it's unlikely you'll get any rows that aren't already unique as I ***assume*** `Tags` has a unique identity column.

Comment: if u use IN then it will return lead with any one of the tags but in our case, we want to make sure both tags are associated with leads. Let say any lead have tag 9 only that will also be returned although we want only who has both 9 and 13

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: Use of distinct is often a sign that the writer does not understand the data model or has written a logically-flawed query (and does understand how to fix it). What is your specific goal? Do you want leads that have ONLY both tags? Leads that have at least one of those tags? Leads that have both tags and any others? Leads that have only 1 tag of each? Those details matter - think first. Show some sample data and expected result to help you and everyone else understand your goal and

Comment: "Leads that have both tags and any others?"

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. You ought to supply DDL, a useful collection of sample input and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Exists.  This will return the Tags information (and Leads ID) for any Lead with rows in both tags of 9 and 17.

```
SELECT distinct [Leads].Id AS LeadId, Tags.* 
FROM [Leads]  
INNER JOIN [AssociateTags] ON [Leads].[Id] = [AssociateTags].[EntityId]
INNER JOIN [Tags] ON [AssociateTags].[TagId] = [Tags].[Id]
WHERE [Leads].[IsDeleted] = cast(0 as bit)  
AND leads.id= 17 
AND EXISTS (Select 1 from [Tags] where [AssociateTags].[TagId] = [Tags].[Id] and [Tags].[ID] = 9)
AND EXISTS (Select 1 from [Tags] where [AssociateTags].[TagId] = [Tags].[Id] and [Tags].[ID] = 13)
```

If you don't really need the Tags information, you can eliminate a join:

```
SELECT distinct [Leads].Id AS LeadId
FROM [Leads]  
INNER JOIN [AssociateTags] ON [Leads].[Id] = [AssociateTags].[EntityId]
WHERE [Leads].[IsDeleted] = cast(0 as bit)  
AND leads.id= 17 
AND EXISTS (Select 1 from [Tags] where [AssociateTags].[TagId] = [Tags].[Id] and [Tags].[ID] = 9)
AND EXISTS (Select 1 from [Tags] where [AssociateTags].[TagId] = [Tags].[Id] and [Tags].[ID] = 13)
```

Comment: [Tags].[ID] = 17 is wrong its 13. But still, it does not return any data too

Comment: @SOFUser It doesn't return any data because the conditions are not met.  Are you sure the tables contain all of the records you think they do?  What happens if you remove the `and exists` clauses?   You would get rows back for every tag associated with Lead 17.  If not, either the data is not there or you are joining the tables incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(ID INT, TAG_ID INT,Name  VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(17 , 9  ,' imported-from-google'),
(17 , 13,'  imported-from-quickbooks'),
(17 , 14,'  imported-from-yahoo')

SELECT * FROM @T WHERE (ID=17 AND TAG_ID=9) OR (ID=17 AND TAG_ID=13)
```

Comment: above query has the same issue it will return a result even if tag_13 does not exist "Leads that have BOTH tags and any others?"

Comment: Try now @SOFUser

Comment: SELECT * FROM @T WHERE (ID=17 AND TAG_ID=9) OR (ID=17 AND TAG_ID=15) it has the same issue if you pass id 15 which does not exist will still return the result with 9 because its OR condition

Comment: Plz, provide more Sample data @SOFUser

Answer (score 0):

For each lead_id the query must first count the rows which contains tag_id's in (9,13).  Then final output can be restricted in the WHERE clause of the outer query.  Here's an example with sample data and then (as best as could without data) applied to the original code.  Something like this

```
/* exmaple */
DECLARE @T TABLE(ID INT, TAG_ID INT,Name  VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(17 , 9  ,' imported-from-google'),
(17 , 13,'  imported-from-quickbooks'),
(17 , 14,'  imported-from-yahoo'),
(18 , 9  ,' imported-from-google'),
(18 , 23,'  imported-from-quickbooks'),
(18 , 14,'  imported-from-yahoo'),
(19 , 13,'  imported-from-quickbooks'),
(19 , 14,'  imported-from-yahoo');

with sum_tags_cte as (
    select *, sum(iif(TAG_ID in(9,13), 1, 0)) over (partition by ID order by (select null)) tags_count
    from @T)
select *
from sum_tags_cte
where tags_count=2;

/* applied to original code */
with sum_tags_cte(LeadId, Id, [Name], tags_count) as (
    SELECT [Leads].Id AS LeadId, Tags.Id, Tags.Name,
            sum(case when TAG_ID in(9,13) then 1 else 0 end) 
                over (partition by ID order by (select null))
    FROM [Leads]  
         JOIN [AssociateTags] ON [Leads].[Id] = [AssociateTags].[EntityId]
         JOIN [Tags] ON [AssociateTags].[TagId] = [Tags].[Id]
    WHERE [Leads].[IsDeleted] = cast(0 as bit))
select LeadId, Id, [Name]
where tags_count=2
      and Id in (9, 13) /* to only display 2 lines */
;
```